# I want to travel to the Netherlands as a non-EU national, but my Russian passport expires in 1 month

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, netherlands, russian-citizens

Here is what I have.

- I am 17 years old, and I have a Russian passport, currently living in greece.
- I've been living in Greece (a European country) from the age of 2.
- I also do have a residence permit that expires in 2021.
- My mother doesn't have a European/Greek passport, but she is married to a Greek/European citizen.
- I want to go to the Netherlands for 2 weeks, with a return ticket. However, 2 weeks after my return, my passport will expire. Basically, my passwort will NOT expire during my stay in the Netherlands, but it will be expire 1 month from today.
- I have traveled to the Netherlands last summer, using my Russian passport and my "residence card of a family member of a Union citizen". I could go through the Greek and the Dutch checks with ease, and I did not need a visa.

Is it definite that I will be stopped from boarding the plane, since my passport expires in a month? (While it should not expire 3 months after my return, since I heard that's a rule).

Take in consideration that I cannot renew my Russian passport more than 2 months before it expires, and it takes 2 months to succesfully renew it. This basically makes it impossible for me to travel anywhere in the EU for this small gap of time. What if I was an adult with a job? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Russian citizens can have two international passports

Comment: Most countries will also issue a new passport before the current one expires, usually canceling the first one in the process.

Comment: Formally, when traveling within the EU, you need both your passport and residence permit. But if you're flying directly from Greece to the Netherlands, most probably there will be no one to check. If checking-in online, with most airlines and in most airports, you won't even need to show any identification to anyone.

Comment: Last time I traveled to the netherlands from greece, I had to show my passport/residence permit both in Greece and in the Netherlands

Comment: @SimonKozlov You mean on **arriving** in the Netherlands? To whom? You just walk to the baggage hall and exit. Or do you mean when checking in for the flight? That makes more sense.

Comment: @coke As I arrived in the netherlands, there were a couple of policemen. They asked for my passport. They also thoroughly checked it, taking about 40 seconds before they let me pass. The guy looked through some scanner with his eye to see if my passport was legit. Now my flight is in 2 days, and I hope all will be good, but I did have to go through 2 cops, one of which spoke greek

Comment: @SimonKozlov This was an exceptional extra check then, because it is **not** normally what happens. Normally you just get off the plane and walk to the baggage claim and the exit. That said, the rules are the rules: because you have a Greek residence permit,your passport (and permit) need only be valid on arrival.

Comment: @SimonKozlov If the check-in staff at bag drop and/or the gate isn't sure whether they can board you, ask them to double-check Timatic **putting in Greece in the "Alien residency" field** (they will then see exactly what I quoted). Remember to present your residence Permit as well as your passport **unless** the boarding pass is enough.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     residents of Greece must be valid **on arrival**.

A generalised search for the Netherlands gives:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     nationals of the Netherlands must be valid on arrival.
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     **residents of** Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Vatican City
>     (Holy See) and **Schengen Member States** must be
>     **valid on arrival**.

So your passport (and residence permit) only has to be valid on the day you enter the Netherlands.

The 3-month rule applies to non-EU/EFTA citizens **not** holding a residence permit in an EU/EFTA country.

Also, there are no border checks between Greece and the Netherlands, so unless flying on a low-cost carrier, you will usually not have to show your passport to check-in staff except if checking in luggage (to see that you're the ticket holder)

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm This doesn't specify anything like what you've mentioned, along with other similar sites. They've stated the same thing, without mentioning any exceptions.

Comment: @SimonKozlov Well, that's the rules for non-residents. Timatic is based on information given by border authorities to IATA, and therefore should normally be trusted over other sources, which may not list complete information (as in this case) or may be outdated. Check-in staff relies on Timatic exclusively

Comment: @SimonKozlov Also, it is international practice that legal residents of a country won't be forced to have a passport valid beyond the date of entry to that country. Schengen is a single country for border purposes, thus your trip is effectively domestic, and all airlines except low-cost ones will treat it as such

Comment: Where can I see this database myself?

Comment: @SimonKozlov For example here http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html Select Russia as the nationality, Greece in "Alien resident of" (**important**) and Netherlands as the destination. Like I said, what you see there is literally what check-in staff will see as well.

Comment: I will fly in a low-cost carrier, however. Is that a problem? I guess it won't be, since if that rule is true, they'll let me pass. I'm just making sure since I'm paranoid about this and I can't afford to lose money.

Comment: @SimonKozlov Low-cost carriers will stick to the Timatic rules. That's the strictest thing they can do - like I said, other airlines normally only check the boarding pass at the gate, meaning a passport practically isn't needed at all. Make sure to present your residence permit as well if asked for your passport.

Comment: I've recently been shown this : https://imgur.com/YWwlcIF What about it? Now I've asked the dutch embassy in greece, a travel agent, and you, and you told me this. But my girlfriend from the netherlands tells me otherwise, according to what she sees in the KLM Airlines website, and even the response she has got from the embassy in the netherlands told her that I cannot travel to the netherlands. This is incredibly confusing and frustrating, I don't know what to trust, I can't afford having 200 euro wasted

Comment: @SimonKozlov That tool (the one you linked) is utter crap; contains so much incorrect info, plus it's **not** what check-in staff uses anywhere. And remember, it all comes down to check-in staff since there is no border control between Greece and the Netherlands. The embassy also is talking a load of rubbish (which is not uncommon); don't trust them.

Comment: @SimonKozlov If you don't feel you can trust Timatic (even though, again, there are no border checks and it's only about you getting on the flight, for which check-in staff uses Timatic), then you can call the Dutch border control at +31 20 603 80 63. **Tell them you have a valid Greek residence Permit**

Comment: @SimonKozlov In short: you're worried of losing your trip, but the only one who could make you lose your trip is check-in staff in Greece, because there'll be no border control in Amsterdam. Check-in staff **will** use Timatic, nothing else; therefore you'll have no problems. What's more, like I said you may only have to show your boarding pass if going hand luggage only

Comment: @SimonKozlov Edited the answer, showing a generalised Timatic search. As you can see, the 3-month rule would apply if you **didn't** have a Greek residence Permit.

Comment: @SimonKozlov If you're still not convinced and want to cancel your trip, that's up to you, but I tell you, what the embassy says means ***nothing***. Once again, there are no border checks, and it's all about the check-in staff in Greece. They don't call around to embassies or whatnot; no, they use Timatic and ***don't care*** about what any other source says. That is the simple fact